# How to set chunk size for HttpRequest/HttpEntity created from a ByteString

Tags: akka-http

If I want to upload a file in akka-http I can use a method like this where I can control the chunk size:

```
  private def createUploadRequest(streamName: String, uri: Uri, path: Path): Future[(HttpRequest, Path)] = {
    val bodyPart = FormData.BodyPart.fromPath("data", ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, path, chunkSize)
    val body     = FormData(bodyPart) 
    Marshal(body).to[RequestEntity].map { entity => 
      HttpRequest(method = HttpMethods.POST, uri = uri, entity = entity) -> path
    }
  }
```

However if I only have a ByteString with the contents and want to upload it, I can't control the chunk size:

```
  private def makeHttpRequest(streamName: String, serverInfo: ServerInfo, bs: ByteString): HttpRequest = {
    HttpRequest(
      HttpMethods.POST,
      s"http://${serverInfo.host}:${serverInfo.port}$distRoute/$streamName",
      entity = HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`, bs)
    )
  }
```

Is there any way to also control the chunk size when creating the HttpEntity from a ByteString?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [`Chunked`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpEntity$$Chunked.html) entity instead of using the [`HttpEntity.apply`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka-http/current/akka/http/scaladsl/model/HttpEntity$.html#apply(contentType:akka.http.scaladsl.model.ContentType,data:akka.util.ByteString):akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Strict) method:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.Chunked
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.HttpEntity.ChunkStreamPart

type ChunkSize = Int

val chunkedEntityFromByteString : ChunkSize => ByteString => Entity = 
  chunkSize => byteString =>
    Chunked(
      ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`,
      Source
        .fromIterator(() => byteString sliding chunkSize)
        .map(ChunkStreamPart.apply)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a minor correction to the posted solution to make it compile:

```
    type ChunkSize = Int

    val chunkedFromByteString : ChunkSize => ByteString => HttpEntity =
      chunkSize => byteString =>
        Chunked(
          ContentTypes.`application/octet-stream`,
          Source
            .fromIterator(() => byteString sliding chunkSize)
            .map(ChunkStreamPart.apply)
        )
```